# Reset default launcher when app is closed

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have created a children's app that has a child lock using a custom launcher, however I have one small problem. When the app is closed and the home button is pressed the dialog to select the default launcher is displayed. Is there are way to reset the default launcher when the app is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make any particular app be the default. However, you could use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`, to disable your activity that has the `HOME` category. Re-enable that when the user wants to have the choice of using your home screen again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you give me an example please? Also I'm trying to reset the default launcher to the android launcher.

Comment: @user1613103: "Also I'm trying to reset the default launcher to the android launcher" -- that is not possible.